# Java coin counter code

Tags: java

Hello I have this code so far to find the less amount of change for a given amount but i keep getting a static error message. And I dont know why.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Coin{
  public static void main (String[] Args){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a number");
  int i = sc.nextInt();
  int q = 25;
  int d = 10;
  int n = 5;
  int p = 1;
  int quarters = (i/q);
  int dimes = i - quarters*25/d;
  int nickels = i - (quarters*25) - (dimes*10)/n;
  int pennies = i - (quarters*25) - (dimes*10) - (nickels*5)/p;
  System.out.println ("Your amount contain the following");
  System.out.println ("quarters:   " + quarters);
  System.out.println ("dimes:    " + dimes);
  System.out.println ("nickels:    " + nickels);
  System.out.println ("pennies:    " + pennies);

}}
```

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Please post the exact error message here.

Comment: Your args parameter should be lower case

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals.. Although true, but that's a convention, and not the source of any error.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals not really, its just a convention that method arguments should start with lowercase

Comment: The code compiles and runs in my eclipse without error messages. Output may not be the intended one.

Comment: @ManuelQuinones Scanner is an API class

Comment: There's no syntax error here, but the output is incorrect. Hint: Use more parenthesis.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR thanks.  I missed that.

Comment: The error message is to long to pst on the comment but if i use a number like 345 it will show me but if i do 3.54 it gives the error message

Comment: edit your question to add the error, instead of posting it as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your comment, you are using the `nextInt()` method of the Scanner class, which will only get an integer.  If you type in a floating point number (like 3.54) it will throw an exception.  You need to instead use [nextFloat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat%28%29) and change the variable `i` to a float.

Comment: While this does address the error, I think that instructing them to represent a monetary value with a double is decidedly bad advice.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of solving what looks very much like a homework problem, I will just point out that the biggest error I see is in operator precedence. In other words, I believe you need more parenthesis.